# Using Core Data while development with many planned changes

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I read this [blog](http://sealedabstract.com/code/you-should-use-core-data/) where he writes, that everyone should use core data as soon as he want to store more than just trivial data.

So I added a xcdatamodeld to my project. I'm going to fill the database in the app with a formular. And I know, that I will change the data model a lot in the future development. But the entered data in the formular have to be saved. This means I need many migrations. Do you think that it is a good idea to use core data at this stage of development? I don't like the idea having tons of old xcdatamodel files while developing.

By the way, I'm using [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) if this helps anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use core data. It's great.

I don't find that it is worth the effort doing migrations while you're developing the app. Half the time you're not saving the data anyway, or you want to start from a clean slate, or you have data setup code you want to test on the new model.

I'd advise altering your core data stack setup code to simply delete and recreate the persistent store if there is an error. Save the migrations for when you're updating a live version of the app.